# Chessboard Wormhole

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I found this picture on the internet and I am trying to rebuild it with Illustrator / Photoshop. Unfortunately I can not find good tutorials. How can I rebuild this?

[image]

Many thanks for your appreciated help!
Kind regards,
Silvan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In Illustrator, make a pattern brush (as shown top left in the example below)
2. Apply the brush to a circle
3. Apply a transform effect in the appearance panel to scale and rotate the circles, and increase the number of copies until it fills the entire shape. Don't use the values shown in the example below. You'll need to adjust the values so it works with the brush and circle you made.
4. To make it look darker in the middle, add circle on top and fill it with a radial gradient (black in the centre, transparent at the edge).

[image]